# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS for Minio via NGINX Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, minio

I have a [Minio](https://min.io/) ClusterIP service running in a Kubernetes cluster. And on top of it, I have a [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). NGINX Ingress needs to forward Minio traffic to the Minio service, and other traffic to their corresponding services.

My Ingress configuration looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: app-service
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /minio/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: minio-service
              servicePort: 9000
```

Once deployed, the app works fine. However, the Minio page has problem, complaining:

```
This page isn’t working
example.mysite.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

And indeed, the requests are kept redirecting. Here is the screenshot from Chrome DevTools' Network console.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Minio always redirects to /minio/, you need to keep `/minio` in the path and pass it on to the Minio service.

When I change its path rule to `- path: /(minio/.*)`, it works. Now the Ingress configuration looks like below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: app-service
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /(minio/.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: minio-service
              servicePort: 9000
```

And I've got the Minio service working in the browser:

[image]

Hope it is helpful.